# How to resolve my jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi I'm trying to change a `<div>` box as the visitor click on some links. And now this is not working as it should. Any help would be highly appreciated on this and Thank you in advance.

```
    //Tab Open events
$("#signUp").click(function(e){
    OpenTabs("#SignUpBox");
});
$("#ForgetPassword").click(function(e){
    OpenTabs("#PasswordResetBox");
});
function OpenTabs(CssId) {

    if(CssId="#SignUpBox"){
        ResetPanelsTo("#SignUpBox");
        ResizePanelTo("#SignUpBox");
        console.log("in if(CssId='#SignUpBox'){");
    }
    if(CssId="#loginBox"){
        ResetPanelsTo("#loginBox");
        ResizePanelTo("#loginBox");
        console.log("in if(CssId='#loginBox'){");
    }
    if(CssId="#PasswordResetBox"){
        ResetPanelsTo("#PasswordResetBox");
        ResizePanelTo("#PasswordResetBox");
        console.log("in if(CssId='#PasswordResetBox'){");
    }
    function ResetPanelsTo(CssId){
        if(CssId="#SignUpBox"){
            $("#PasswordResetBox").css("display","none");
            $("#SignUpBox").css("display","block");
            $("#loginBox").css("display", "none");
            console.log("ResetPanelsTo SignUpBox");
        }
        if (CssId="#PasswordResetBox"){
            $("#SignUpBox").css("display","none");
            $("#PasswordResetBox").css("display","block");
            $("#loginBox").css("display", "none");
            console.log("ResetPanelsTo PasswordResetBox");
        }
        if (CssId="#loginBox"){
            $("#SignUpBox").css("display","none");
            $("#PasswordResetBox").css("display","none");
            $("#loginBox").css("display", "block");
            console.log("ResetPanelsTo loginBox");
        }
    }

    function ResizePanelTo(CssId) {
        if (CssId = "#SignUpBox") {
            $(".panel").css({
                left: "531px",
                top: "-90px",
                width: "360px",
                height: "350px",
                'border-radius': '5px'
            });
            console.log("ResizePanelTo SignUpBox");
        }

        if (CssId = "#PasswordResetBox") {
            $(".panel").css({
                left: "531px",
                top: "-90px",
                width: "360px",
                height: "110px",
                'border-radius': '5px'
            });
            console.log("ResizePanelTo panel");
        }

        if (CssId = "#loginBox"){
                $(".login_panel").css({ left: "0px", top: "0px", width: "220px", height: "161px", background: "#f4f4f4", 'border-radius': '0' });
                console.log("ResizePanelTo login_panel");
        }
        }

    }
```

Comment: What's not working? Specific errors in the console? Don't just dump a ton of code with no reasonable explanation!

Comment: You should replace all these If by a Switch.

Comment: Can you show your html as well?

Comment: How about you try debugging yourself first. Go away and read up on JQuery as your code demonstrates a lack of basic understanding.

Comment: Demonstrate the complete code in Fiddle.

Answer (score 3):

All your "if" are bad

It's :

```
if(CssId == "#..."){
```

not :

`if(CssId = "#...")`{

"=" is not like "=="

Comment: That's for a start. Most of it are actually useless anyway

Comment: @Bartdude I think this is the right.  I consider it as a big bug.